# When reviewing should I wait until grace period is over before commenting or/and flagging a post?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

During a review to a new user's first post (which was deleted quite soon) I added a "standard" comment starting

> Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good
>   question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ...

Soon after that another user commented that OP was possibly yet editing that post and was suggesting that my comment was issued too early and I might need to give more time to OP to edit.

I partially agree on that but I also think that any post should be quite ready - and I do not mean now to stick to some typos or so but severe format/off-topic issues - already when posted.

And if it is like I suggest in the title why would the commenting/flagging be enabled at all during the grace period?

Comment: Comments are never too early. They can go stale quickly though.

Comment: Comments break the grace period. This technique was in wide use a while back (not sure anymore) to combat a number of spam, abusive, non-answer posts that were being added, then edited within the grace period to remove the problem. I figured the spammers were doing this to get the spam flaggers flag banned so they could further pedal their fine discount gucci handbags. Posts should be of adequate quality the moment they are posted, not at some point later on.

Comment: [How soon should I vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022) Same answer, same reasons.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks, the accepted answer is exactly as I see it.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes and do you see it as a problem when it happens that I get a question in a review like _asked 2 mins ago_?

Comment: @Pirho No, I don't see that as a problem. I rarely take the time that has passed between a post's creation and my review of it into account.

Comment: At the time you read the question it is what it is. No point in assuming it might get better or worrying about how long ago it was asked. Assume nothing else will happen to it and act accordingly